# how to insert data in 1 table and update another table in a sql database using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have a save button that will add new data in my 'IncidentActions' table and at the same time update 3 columns in my 'Incident' table.

How would i go about doing this

Here is a the C# code i am using to try and accomplish this.

```
protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Context db = new Context();

        // This will check the Action from the actions table and 
        var actionID = (from i in db.Actions
                       where i.Actions == tbActionType.Text
                       select i.ActionsID).First();

        long ID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["IncidentID"]);


        // TODO: update the incident table accordingly
        IncidentAction act = new IncidentAction
        {
            IncidentID = ID,
            ActionDate = (DateTime)dpActionDate.SelectedDate,
            ActionsID = Convert.ToInt32(actionID),
            StatusID = statID,
            IsPublic = false,
            Title = tbTitle.Text.Trim(),
            PeriodValue = Convert.ToInt64(txtDuration.Text),
            Description = txtDescription.Text.Trim(),
            EstimatedCost = txtEstimatedCost.Text == string.Empty ? (decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(txtEstimatedCost.Text),
            ActualCost = txtActualCost.Text == string.Empty ? (decimal?)null : Convert.ToDecimal(txtActualCost.Text),
            LastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
            UpdatedBy = Convert.ToString(loggedInUserName),
            CreatedByUserID = Convert.ToInt32(loggedInUserID),
            Active = true
        };


                db.IncidentActions.Add(act);
                db.SaveChanges();

                Incident inc = new Incident
                {
                    IncidentID = ID,
                    StatusID = statID_new,
                    IncidentPendingDate = DateTime.Now
                };
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem at the moment?

Comment: ah its all good dudes,

i got it sorted :D

ill post my answer tomoro once i am able to answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

One problem seems to be that you're not referencing the correct `Incident` record from the database. You can query the database first to get the record you want to update.

If you want to do them both at the 'same time' (i.e. in the same transaction), remove the first `db.SaveChanges()`. Then the second one will do the insert and update at together.

Also, `DateTime.Now` can return a different value every time it's called. If you want the time stamps to match on each record, simply call `DateTime.Now` once, save the result to a variable, and use it in both places.

Something like this:

```
Context db = new Context();
var now = DateTime.Now;

IncidentAction act = new IncidentAction
{
    IncidentID = ID,
    ...
    LastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
};


db.IncidentActions.Add(act);

Incident inc = db.Incidents.First(i => i.IncidentID == ID);
inc.StatusID = statID_newl
inc.IncidentPendingDate = now;

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

i did sort it out thank you

i changed this code

```
db.IncidentActions.Add(act);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Incident inc = new Incident
            {
                IncidentID = ID,
                StatusID = statID_new,
                IncidentPendingDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            db.SaveChanges();
```

to this

```
// add to the IncidentAction table.
                db.IncidentActions.Add(act);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Update the Incident Table.
                Incident inc = (from i in db.Incidents
                                where i.IncidentID == ID
                                select i).First();

                inc.StatusID = statID_new,
                inc.IncidentPendingDate = DateTime.Now;
                db.SaveChanges();
```